# Add a circle around the marker, when marker becomes visible

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps-extensions

Currently I am using Google Maps Android API Utility for clustering, but I didn't find the way to add a circle around the marker when it becomes visible/rendered from the cluster. I want each marker to have a circle around it. IS there any way in Android maps Extension library to achieve this ?

This is when clustered 
[image: when clustered]

When Cluster Rendered current behavior

[image: When rendered cluster this is the current behavior]

Desired behavior

[image: Desired behavior]

Comment: could you post the photoshop image which you are looking for?

Comment: @Shanmugapriyan I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this library for clustering can help you. Android Maps Extensions https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions

[Android Get the markers that are not clustered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748401/android-get-the-markers-that-are-not-clustered)

If you just need to change marker's icon, you can make png-image (for example, with default marker icon and circle) and paste it to marker as resource.

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_circle)));
```

If you need custom circle, you create it programmatically, but you still need custom marker icon (and of course provide different versions (hdpi, xhdpi...) for resize)

```
// circle
int diameter = 500;
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(diameter, diameter, Bitmap.Config.A
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
canvas.drawCircle(diameter / 2, diameter / 2, diameter / 2, p);


// marker icon through Drawable
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_icon, null);
// you should choose bounds
// drawable.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
drawable.draw(canvas);

//OR marker icon through Bitmap
Bitmap bmIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.marker_icon);
// choose correct top and left margin
canvas.drawBitmap(bmIcon, diameter / 2, diameter / 2, p);


map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm)));
```

Comment: is there any way in this library to add circles on markers and remove those circles when markers are reclustered ?

Comment: I can can not use the png image because the radius of my circle varies.

Comment: have you used this library before? I was trying to integrate it now and I am getting map as null when I do   map = mapFragment.getExtendedMap(); and I verified my mapFragment is not null. This is how I am creating mapFragment         mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
        if (mapFragment == null) {
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction tx = fm.beginTransaction();
            tx.add(R.id.map_container, mapFragment);
            tx.commit();
        }

Comment: Yes, I'm using it and it's good. You should take map by async method mapFragment.getExtendedMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mMap = googleMap;
                setUpMap();
            }
        });

Comment: @Akshay but you can use my last solution with circle in pure google maps, you don't need this library for that

Comment: but How can I cluster the markers then .because I have to set around 10K markers on the map. When I try to launch map it gives StackOverflow Error because of so many markers. So I need Clustering

Comment: @Akshay for clustering you can use Google Maps Android API Utility or Android Maps Extensions, what you like more. But as I understand, this thread is about circle drawing. Is this problem solved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85242/discussion-between-akshay-and-pengrad).

Answer (score 0):

Google maps now has an [API for drawing a circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/model/CircleOptions#getRadius()) you can use it combined with a simple marker, it should do the same effect